# Escaping "#" sign

Tags: bash, escaping, wget

I am trying to use wget with a url that includes a "#" sign. No matter what I do to escape the character, it doesn't work. I've used \, ', and ". But none of them work. Does any one have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Tried to UrlEncode it as %23  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send it as %23 if you really mean for it to have a hash. If you're trying to send a fragment, don't bother since the server won't care about it regardless.

Comment: This is what I have, but it still doesn't work wget -a "${LOG_FILE}" -O "${HOME_DIR}/search_results.txt" "http://${APP_SERVER}:${APACHE_PORT}/atlas%23plate=${search_term}&atlas=1&structure=549"

Comment: Uh, are you sure you didn't want a question mark there instead?

Comment: Then it's a fragment. Read the answer again.

Comment: I didn't know what you meant by fragment. Yes it sounds like this is a fragment. So I should just ignore it?

Comment: Change it to a ?. Just trust me. That's what you want.

Comment: I tried ?, but it didn't work. It couldn't find it. It's looking for #.

Comment: The error I got after using ? instead of # is about something else. So, using ? instead of # worked. Thanks.

Comment: How about you start telling us what errors you're getting if you want assistance? We're neither psychic nor good guessers.

Comment: The error I was getting was a connection problem because the server was down :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe put uri around`''` ? I believe it works

Answer (score 0):

Are you quoting the url? It shouldn't be a problem if you are.

My guess is you're doing something like:

```
wget http://foo.com/#!/blah
```

Instead of:

```
wget "http://foo.com/#!/blah"
```

`#` is the shell script comment character.

Comment: Yes I am quoting the url, but it still ignores the rest of the url when I run it. wget -a "${LOG_FILE}" -O "${HOME_DIR}/search_results.txt" "http://${APP_SERVER}:${APACHE_PORT}/atlas#plate=${search_term}&atlas=1&structure=549"

Comment: Don't you mean atlas? and not atlas#? Looks like you're making a GET request with parameters. That sperator is ?, not #.

Comment: no it's a #. It sounds like this is a fragment. So it just gets ignored.